# How can I find my UDID on my android phone?

Tags: android

A developer is building an app for me and he need my ID so that he can send the APK file so that I can test the app. The developer need my UDID so that he can send me the APK file. So how do I go about finding my UDID from my android?

Comment: I wonder if he is hard coding it in his app to prevent you from distributing the APK.

Comment: UDID is an iOS thing.  It doesn't exist on Android.  There is the device id, which is similar.

Comment: Android docs - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

Comment: Your developer could easily send you the apk file in multiple other ways that don't require your device's id. Check out this doc: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html

Answer (score 2):

Android phones don't use a udid. That is something for iPhones and apples provisioning system. In this case you need to find in your advanced options where you can allow the install of unknown APK's and then the file your developer sends can be installed.